# Reference to Pointer (*&) syntax

Tags: c++, c, pointers, struct, reference

I'm looking at a piece of code that is sending commands from one piece of hardware to another. A snippet is below.

```
unsigned char data[3];

msg_header *mHead; //pointer of struct msg_header
mHead = (msg_header *) &data; 

mHead->startByte = START_BYTE;
mHead->ID = GET_TELEM; //0x30
mHead->length = 0;
```

The structure msg_header is defined in the header file.

```
typedef struct {
unsigned char startByte;    
unsigned char ID;
unsigned char length;   
//  unsigned char from;
} msg_header;
```

Can someone explain what the `mHead = (msg_header *) &data;` is actually doing?
I know that *& is creating a reference to the pointer pointing to data, but why is msg_header in parantheses and why is it included?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: *"I know that *& is creating a reference to the pointer pointing to data"* ... The parentheses matter in this case, as an operation known as a [C-style cast](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/50442/c-style-casts-or-c-style-casts).  So you cannot pull the * out of the cast and bind it to the & in front of data and have them cancel out.  It's completely different.  Being sly like this and looking like ordinary parentheses grouping is one of the reasons to avoid C-style casts if you are programming in C++, but they are also not as specific as C++ casts are.

Comment: int i, *j;j=&i; no reference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's casting the address of `data` to a `msg_header*` type - pointer to `msg_header`.

There's no reference to speak of. `&` can be used to get the address of a variable.

Comment: I'm still a little confused by what `msg_header*` actually is. I've seen `*` before variables or structures to indicate dereferencing or pointer declaration, but I'm not sure what it means for the `*` to follow something.

Comment: @MIT_noob as Joachim says, symbols mean different things in *declarators* than they mean in *expressions*. This is a bit confusing at first. In this case `msg_header *` is a declarator that is describing a *type*, which is *pointer to `msg_header`*.  Another example is that `int x = 5;` (a *declaration*) the `=` is part of the declaration; however in `x = 5` (an *expression*), the `=` is the assignment operator.

Answer (score 4):

Many operators do different things in different situations. The ampersand, for example, can be used to mark something as a reference (C++ specific), it can be used as a bitwise and operation, or it can be used to get the address of something.

In your case it's the last thing. It's getting the address of the array `data`, which is then casted to a pointer to a structure. So it's an expression with two distinct operations.

Comment: Nitpick: when `&` is used as part of a declarator, it isn't an operator

Answer (score 2):

The thing what `mHead = (msg_header *) &data;` does is writing the address of `data` to the `mHead`. After this 'mHead' points the same address what 'data' pointed to before. This is bacause `ampersand`'s work in this case is to return the address. But in this particular case

you can do the same even without `&`, like this `mHead = (msg_header *) data;` which is exactly the same for this case. This is because the array is an address itself.

To understand it better you can run experiment with printing all the stuff. I add to your code such a printing.

```
typedef struct {
unsigned char startByte;    
unsigned char ID;
unsigned char length;   
//  unsigned char from;
} msg_header;

int main (void)
{
 unsigned char data[3];

 printf ("\nThe address of my data[3] is: 0x%x\n",data);
 printf ("The address of my data[3] is: 0x%x\n",& data);
 printf ("The address of my data[3] is: 0x%x\n\n",& data[0]);
 msg_header *mHead; //pointer of struct msg_header

 //printf ("The address of my mHead is: 0x%x\n", mHead);
 printf ("The address of my mHead, is: 0x%x\n\n",& mHead);


 mHead = (msg_header *) &data; 

 printf ("The pointer of my `mHead`, AFTER it is set, is: 0x%x\n\n", mHead);

 printf ("The `int` value kept in the location of my `mHead` points to, BEFORE the pointer is set: 0x%x\n\n", * mHead);
 printf ("The `unsigned char` value kept in the location of my mHead points to, BEFORE the pointer is set: 0x%x\n\n", *(unsigned char *) mHead);

 mHead->startByte = 0xAA;


 printf ("The `int` value kept in the location of my `mHead` points to, AFTER the pointer is set: 0x%x\n\n", * mHead);
 printf ("The `unsigned char` value kept in the location of my `mHead` points to, AFTER the pointer is set: 0x%x\n\n", *(unsigned char *)  mHead);
 mHead->ID = 0x30; //0x30
 mHead->length = 0;
}
```

On my platform I got the output below, but in your case it will definitely different. However technically it works the same way on every platform, almost.

> The address of my data[3] is: 0xb4ea01a0 The address of my data[3] is:
>   0xb4ea01a0 The address of my data[3] is: 0xb4ea01a0
>
> The address of my mHead, is: 0xb4ea01a8
>
> The pointer of my `mHead`, AFTER it is set, is: 0xb4ea01a0
>
> The `int` value kept in the location of my `mHead` points to, BEFORE
>   the pointer is set: 0xb4ea0290
>
> The `unsigned char` value kept in the location of my mHead points to,
>   BEFORE the pointer is set: 0x90
>
> The `int` value kept in the location of my `mHead` points to, AFTER
>   the pointer is set: 0xb4ea02aa
>
> The `unsigned char` value kept in the location of my `mHead` points
>   to, AFTER the pointer is set: 0xaa

I better show you all relevant things you are interested in at the picture with highlights.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

May be this can help you visualize what's happening -

Typically, the layout of `struct msg_header` in memory would be like

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| startByte |    ID     |   length  |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|<-1 byte ->|<-1 byte ->|<-1 byte ->|
```

and, layout of array `unsigned char data[3];`

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|  data[0]  |  data[1]  |  data[2]  |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|<-1 byte ->|<-1 byte ->|<-1 byte ->|
```

The expression

```
(msg_header *) &data;
```

casts the (layout of) the array `data` to that of the struct `msg_header` so that individual bytes can be read into the struct.

Parentheses are used here to group operators and force a different precedence.
http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm